# Confused on bounds for a triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Q: Integrate $f(x, y, z) = 3x^2y^2$ over the solid bounded above by the cylinder $y^2 + z = 9$, below by the plane $y + z = 3$, and on the sides by the planes $x = 0$ and $x = 2$.

**Possible answer choices**:

- 126
- 50
- 1539/20
- 125
- 1539/10
- None of the above

**My work**:

- I believe dzdydx order is easiest based on the given info.

  - $z$ bounds: $3 - y \le z \le 9 - y^2$
  - $x$ bounds: $0 \le x \le 2$ (given)
- However, how do you get the middle y bounds this way? I'm having a hard time visualizing the $xy$ projection. At first I thought it might be making $z = 0$ in the given $z$ equations to get $-3 \le y \le 3$ but something feels "off" about that way. The answer by that method gives $432/5$.
- "None of the above" is an answer choice, but usually the actual answer is similar to the given choices. Can someone give some guidance on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean to write $y^2+z^2=9$ for the cylinder?

Comment: I double checked the question and that's how it is written: y + z^2 = 9. Parabolic cylinder, right?

Comment: Oh ok. I wouldn't call that a cylinder but that might depend on where you live.

Comment: *y^2 + z = 9 is what I meant (same as in the post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $y^2+z=9$ and $y+z=3$ do not contain $x$, you can visualize these curves as bounding a region in the $yz$-plane.  Then the solid is the cylinder whose base is this region and whose height is in the $x$ direction.

Obtaining the bounds for $y$ and $z$ amounts to describing this region.  The parabola and the line intersect when $9-y^2=3-y$, i.e. $y = -2,3$.  So, $-2 \leq y \leq 3$.

Comment: Thanks! I usually do the 2d projection on the last two variables (so dydx or xy plane here) so I got confused when there were no y bounds after I drew x = 0 to x = 2. The middle bounds usually have a function so kind of weird just to have constant numbers there, but the yz projection does make sense.